# Trying to login with google but always return null

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

hey guys i trying to login with google using firebase in flutter but its always return null in the next page

how can i get the current user in the next page after login with google

i already connect with firebase and generate sha-1 and sha-256

here's the code

login button

```
onPressed: () async {
      setState(() {
        _isSigningIn = true;
      });

      try {
        final user = await googleSignIn.signIn();
        final googleAuth = await user.authentication;

        final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
            accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
            idToken: googleAuth.idToken
        );

        final googleAccount = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

        if(googleAccount != null) {
          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, HomeScreen.id);
        }
      } catch (e) {
        final snackbar = SnackBar(content: Text(e.toString()));
        _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackbar);
      } finally {
        setState(() {
          _isSigningIn = false;
        });
      }
    },
```

home_screen.dart

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  User _currentUser;

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      var currentUser = await _auth.currentUser;

      if (currentUser != null) {
        _currentUser = currentUser;
      }
    } catch(e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_currentUser.email),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is an asynchronous function, it is for this reason that you receive null, you must add an await.

`final googleAccount = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);`

In addition to this, to access the information of the current user you must do it this way.

`googleAccount.user`